# Local variable referenced before assignment - error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This function should add 1 to a number given in the form of a list.
If the list is `[1, 2, 3]`, then this function should return `[1, 2, 4]` because `123 + 1 == 124`.

Below is the function in question:

```
def plusOne(self, A):
    val = 1;
    for i in range(len(A)-1,0,-1):
        val = val + A[i]
        borrow = int(val/10)
        if borrow == 0:
            A[i] = val
            break;
        else:
            A[i] = val%10
            val = borrow
    A = [borrow] + A
    while A[0]==0:
        del A[0]
    return A
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 225, in 
    Z = obj.plusOne(A)
  File "/tmp/judge/solution.py", line 8, in plusOne
    A = [borrow] + A
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'borrow' referenced before assignment
```

And surprisingly the below code runs without any error:

```
class Solution:
    # @param A : list of integers
    # @return a list of integers
    def plusOne(self, A):
        val = 1;
        for i in range(len(A),0,-1):
            val = val + A[i-1]
            borrow = int(val/10)
            if borrow == 0:
                A[i-1] = val
                break;
            else:
                A[i-1] = val%10
                val = borrow
        A = [borrow] + A
        while A[0]==0:
            del A[0]
        return A
```

I still do not understand that if initializing the borrow variable directly inside the loop is causing the error then the above snippet should throw the error too, right?

Comment: this function doesn't seem to be related to a class, if it isn't - try removing the `self` argument.

Comment: This would happen if the `for` loop did not execute - and thus `borrow` was never initialized inside of it. What are you calling this function with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is a classic problem of *scoping*.

The variable `borrow` is not defined before the `for` loop and the code tries to access it after the loop.

If the `len(A) > 1`, your code will work perfectly because in that case `borrow` is defined in the loop and loop is being executed.

But, if the `len(A) <= 1`, in such case the code is directly trying to access the variable `borrow`, which has never been defined before.

In such scenarios, the best practice is to define the variables with a default value.
In this case `borrow = 0`, would be the correct value, if you define it before the `for` loop.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

borrow is getting declared/initialized inside the `for` loop.

```
for i in range(len(A)-1,0,-1):
```

What if len(A) is 1 then there wont be any range to loop through and borrow will never come into scope, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code. It does work as intended, in most cases. Allow me to suggest few improvements and point out the problems.

First of all, you have two semicolons in your code, they are not needed in Python.
`(line 2) val = 1;` and `(line 8) break;`

Second, when lists are sent to methods and functions they are sent as reference, and as such, changes inside those methods would apply to the original list.

Third, a break within a loop usually shows a wrong choice and planning.

Fourth, if `plusOne` is not part of a class then there is no need for `self` as it's parameters (if it is part of a class then leave it there and call using `self.plusOne(..)` when calling.

Here is how I would have done that, for different point of view:

```
def plusOne(self, lst):
    if len(lst) > 0:
        # Initial value to increase by
        val = 1
        # Initialization of list index to last element.
        i = -1
        # Calculate the number after addition, calculate the borrow and replace in the list.
        num = val + lst[i]
        borrow = num // 10
        lst[i] = num % 10
        # While there is any borrow and the list didn't read the first element.
        while borrow != 0 and i > len(lst)*-1:
            # Update the borrow to new value.
            val = borrow
            # Decrease the index.
            i -= 1
            # Calculate the number after addition, calculate the borrow and replace in the list.
            num = val + lst[i]
            borrow = num // 10
            lst[i] = num % 10

        # Check if borrow remaining after index out of range.
        if borrow != 0:
            # Insert borrow before the first element.
            lst.insert(0, borrow)
        # Remove leading zeros.
        while lst[0] == 0:
            del lst[0]


def main():
    lst = [1, 2, 9]
    plusOne('', lst)
    print(lst)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```